# User Session ID as a Parameter in an Ajax Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, httphandler

I have created an **HttpHandler** that I will be using with a **jquery-Ajax** call.

This **HttpHandler** will access the database and check something related to the **currently singed in user**.

The user is considered signed in by using the Session, with an attribute called **user_id**.

```
Session["user_id"] = userId;
```

I tried to retrieve this **Session** in the **HttpHandler** but that doesn't seem to work.

So I thought about sending the user_id as a **parameter**.

```
    var user_id = //Retrieved in some way...
    $.ajax({
        url: 'QuestionRate.ashx?id=user_id',
        success: function (msg, status, xhr) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

But this really seems like a bad idea, anyone who will read the codes can simply access the Handler with the id that he wants.

So what can I do in this situation? I want the Handler to get the user_id for database access, yet I wanna make sure that this user_id is the actual id of the signed in user. There's no way to access the Session in the Handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing session id with an ajax call doesn't sound good.

You should mark your handler with the marker [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) interface and access to session as read-only via `HttpContext.Current.Session` instance.

---

Code sample:

```
public class FooHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState 
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string user_id = context.Session["user_id"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer with a small example of how this Handler will look like? I'm really not that good in C#.

Comment: BRILLIANT, it worked, I was trying to use context.Session["user_id"] but it didn't work, I needed to implement this interface, but I didn't know how to implement interfaces :D I worked on Java a lot, I hate when I need to move to another language which is very similar, everything feels..weird..

Answer (score 2):

Make your handler implement **[`IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)**, that will notify ASP.NET that your handler uses Session state. Then the session cookie sent from the client will be recognized by the handler and you can access it on serverside as in any other aspx page for example.

Also you can use **`IReadOnlySessionState`** for read-only Session access.

Answer (score 1):

What you're going to want to do is turn it into a `POST` and add it to the `POST` data. Then when coupled with an SSL key, the `POST` data will automatically be encrypted. So what you can try is:

```
var user_id = //Retrieved in some way...
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    url: 'QuestionRate.ashx',
    data: { userid: user_id }
    success: function (msg, status, xhr) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

then in your HTTP Handler you can just pull that off using the `Request` object.

[jQuery AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Nice idea, implementing SSL could be a hassle though if you haven't got a certificate.

Comment: @Liam, yes that's true, but that's pretty easy these days when Windows Server 2008 is its own certificate server. And further, if the OP is concerned about security (i.e. the session key being compromised) running a website without SSL makes security a moot point and thus if you're not using SSL simply pass it in the query string.

Comment: V true, SSL is the only **true** way to secure a connection.

Comment: By using POST, this automatically means that it will be using SSL? or what? should I do something else?

Comment: Using `POST` means that you're posting data rather than getting data, like a `form` post. To use SSL you simply need to apply a certificate to your web server *after* either purchasing one *or* creating your own via Windows Server 2008. How exactly you need to get the certificate, I can't answer, you need to figure that one out based on your needs.