# Determine if session has timed out when making an ajax call to httphandler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm making jQuery ajax calls to a httphandler (.ashx). Is there any way to know if the session has timed out before making an ajax request?

If a timeout has occured i will get the login page specified in my web.config as response to the ajax call instead of my regular JSON.

A quick and ugly solution would be to assume that each time I end up in the `error` callback it is because i get HTML as response when the datatype is set to JSON. But I suppose there is a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must try for [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) interface.

[Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070346/user-session-id-as-a-parameter-in-an-ajax-call)